# ¿Qué pasa cuando clono una base de datos en mysql?

Tags: mysql, servidor, virtualización

Resulta que tengo un servidor, con el cual estoy haciendo pruebas para posterior a esto poder hacerlo virtualizado, para que me permitan continuar con la virtualización me están pidiendo saber una serie de cosas, entre ellas saber clonar una base de datos por si llegara a caerse el servidor, he buscado algunas formas de como hacerlo, encontré esta que fue la que más sencilla me pareció

***Crear la base de datos (nombre) en el servidor.

mysql> CREATE DATABASE clon_ddbb;

Clonamos la base de datos ddbb (debe estar previamente creada como vimos en el paso anterior).

mysqldump -u [usuario] -p[password] ddbb | mysql -u [usuario] -p[password] clon_ddbb***

Pero como soy nueva y he empezado desde 0 estos temas aun tengo muchas dudas, como ¿para poner el primer comando tengo que iniciar sesión con el usuario de la base de datos que quiero clonar?

¿Una vez que haya ejecutado esos dos comandos tendré disponible la base de datos para cuando la necesite, o tendré que usarla de inmediato?

¿Esto afectará mi base de datos original?

¿Podré volver a clonarla?

¿Hacen falta más cosas o con esos dos comandos basta?

¿Algún otra cosa que tenga que saber antes de querer llegar a la virtualización, así como esto de tener un clon de mi base de datos?

De antemano muchas gracias

Comment: En tu servidor es muy dificil hacer funcionar phpmyadmin..?

Comment: Clonar es lo mismo que copiar. es una copia exacta, por lo tanto es una nueva base de datos, por mas que tenga exactamente la misma estructura y los mismos datos, es otra base de datos. De ahi en mas, todas las respuestas son: es otra base de datos...

Comment: Gracias, saludos

Answer (score 0):

1. Si
2. Tendrás ambas original y copia
3. No, pero si actualizas la copia, la original se mantendrá intacta
4. Si, si no la eliminas
5. Bastaría
6. No sabría decirte...

Un saludo!!

Comment: Gracias, saludos

Comment: Disculpa, tengo una duda más, para utilizar la base de datos clon sin dañar mi información bastaría con eliminar la anterior y cambiarle el nombre al clon por exactamente el mismo nombre de la original, o es necesario realizar un volcado a la base de datos?